# When there are multi using statement, will they be execute in order?

Tags: c#, dispose, using, using-statement

for example

```
  using (Stream ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream())       // a             
  using (FileStream localFileStream = (new FileInfo(localFilePath)).Create()) // b
  {
                 ........do something
  }
```

will the two statement a and b executed in the order i put?
and displose in the same order as well??

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They will execute in textual order, and be disposed in *reverse* order - so `localFileSream` will be disposed first, then `ftpStream`.

Basically your code is equivalent to:

```
using (Stream ftpStream = ...)
{
    using (FileStream localFileStream = ...)
    {
        // localFileStream will be disposed when leaving this block
    }
    // ftpStream will be disposed when leaving this block
}
```

It goes further than that though. Your code is *also* equivalent (leaving aside the different type of `localFileStream`) to this:

```
using (Stream ftpStream = ..., localFileStream = ...)
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.** This syntax is just a shortcut or alternative way of nesting `using` statements. All you're doing is omitting the brackets on the first `using` statement. It's equivalent to:

```
using (Stream ftpStream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
    using (FileStream localFileStream = (new FileInfo(localFilePath)).Create())
    {
        //insert your code here
    }
}
```